# Groupby, Transform by Ranking

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, transform, rank

I am trying to do a `groupby` `transform by rank` with the condition of the same value will rank in ascending order (`method='first'`) and ranking will be by descending (`ascending=False`). Rather than doing a `groupby` rank and `pandas merge`.

Sample code for `groupby` rank and `pandas merge`:

```
data = {
    "id": [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5],
    "value": [10,10,20,20,30,30,40,40,20,20]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_rank = df.drop_duplicates()
df_rank["rank"] = df_rank["value"].rank(method="first", ascending=False)

df = pd.merge(df, df_rank[["id","rank"]], on="id", how="left")
df
Out[71]: 
   id  value  rank
0   1     10   5.0
1   1     10   5.0
2   2     20   3.0
3   2     20   3.0
4   3     30   2.0
5   3     30   2.0
6   4     40   1.0
7   4     40   1.0
8   5     20   4.0
9   5     20   4.0
```

I want it to be done by `groupby` `transform` method or a more `optimized` solution. Thanks!

Comment: Is it your expected output?

Comment: @MykolaZotko cell 71 is my expected output.

Comment: I don't think there is a better solution.